# unable to call REST API from browser

Tags: rest, restful-authentication

My REST API with basic authentication works fine using Rest client (Google Chrome extn).
The same also working fine with below Curl command:

curl --header "Accept:application/json" -i --user user1:user1Pass http://localhost:8080/authenticate

But when testing the same in browser I'm getting 404 not found error. The browser URL: http://user1.user1Pass@localhost:8080/authenticate

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a period instead of a colon.

Comment: There was typo error. I have used as below, but still not working: user1:user1Pass@localhost:8080/authenticate

Answer (score 0):

The format of the url should be http://user1: user1Pass@localhost:8080/authenticate

The main point is you need to separate username and password by colon.

Comment: Thanks Ram. There was typo error. I have used as below, but still not working:  http://user1:user1Pass@localhost:8080/authenticate